# Solr behind Drupal returns too many results for specific query

Tags: search, drupal, solr

We've got Solr sat behind one of our client's Drupal 7 websites, and while it's working well, it returns too many results for what should be quite specific queries. (It also has relevance/weighting problems; but I'm hoping that solving this problem will remove the - literally - irrelevant results.)

For example, searching for the phrase 'particular phrase in london' should return the node with that as its title, quite high up; I don't even think that any other content should be returned. But I find that it's returning lots of content, purely on the fact that it mentions "London"!

Frivolously, searching for the ridiculous phrase 'piecrusts in london' returns a lot of results too, apparently just because they mention London. No content on the site mentions actual piecrusts.

When I search for 'particular phrase in london', here are the parameters that end up in the catalina.out log on the server (whitespace added for clarity):

```
{spellcheck=false&facet=true&f.im_field_health_topic.facet.mincount=1
 &facet.mincount=1&f.ds_created.facet.date.gap=%2B1YEAR
 &spellcheck.q=particular+phrase+in+london
 &qf=taxonomy_names^2.0&qf=path_alias^5.0&qf=content^40&qf=label^21.0
 &qf=tos_content_extra^1.0&qf=ts_comments^20&qf=tm_vid_3_names^200
 &facet.date=ds_created
 &f.ds_created.facet.date.start=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z/YEAR
 &f.bundle.facet.mincount=1&hl.fl=content,ts_comments
 &json.nl=map&wt=json&rows=10&fl=id,entity_id,entity_type,bundle,bundle_name,
   label,is_comment_count,ds_created,ds_changed,score,path,url,is_uid,
   tos_name,tm_node,zs_entity
 &start=0&facet.sort=count&f.bundle.facet.limit=50&q=special+phrase+in+london
 &f.ds_created.facet.date.end=2012-01-01T00:00:00Z%2B1YEAR/YEAR
 &bf=recip(ms(NOW,ds_created),3.16e-11,1,1)^150.0
 &facet.field=im_field_health_topic&facet.field=bundle
 &f.im_field_health_topic.facet.limit=50&f.ds_created.facet.limit=50}
hits=1998 status=0 QTime=14
```

Note that these parameters have been built by Drupal's Apache Solr module; I don't believe we've got any particular custom code of our own that's doing anything to it.

This corresponds to the following URL, if entered directly in the browser:

http://example.com:8081/solr/CLIENT/select?spellcheck=false&facet=true&f.im_field_health_topic.facet.mincount=1&facet.mincount=1&f.ds_created.facet.date.gap=%2B1YEAR&spellcheck.q=particular+phrase+in+London&qf=taxonomy_names^2.0&qf=path_alias^5.0&qf=content^40&qf=label^21.0&qf=tos_content_extra^1.0&qf=ts_comments^20&qf=tm_vid_3_names^200&facet.date=ds_created&f.ds_created.facet.date.start=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z/YEAR&f.bundle.facet.mincount=1&hl.fl=content,ts_comments&json.nl=map&wt=json&rows=10&fl=id,entity_id,entity_type,bundle,bundle_name,label,is_comment_count,ds_created,ds_changed,score,path,url,is_uid,tos_name,tm_node,zs_entity&start=0&facet.sort=count&f.bundle.facet.limit=50&q=particular+phrase+in+London&f.ds_created.facet.date.end=2012-01-01T00:00:00Z%2B1YEAR/YEAR&bf=recip(ms(NOW,ds_created),3.16e-11,1,1)^150.0&facet.field=im_field_health_topic&facet.field=bundle&f.im_field_health_topic.facet.limit=50&f.ds_created.facet.limit=50

This URL returns nearly 2000 results - that's most of the content on the site! I've experimented with removing each query parameter at a time, and the only one to make any difference seems to be qf and q: if I remove qf, zero results; if I remove q, I get more results back!

I guess there are two questions here:

1. Is there anything in these parameters that tell Solr "don't worry if 'particular phrase', or 'piecrusts' appears: just collate the results for 'london'" and then order by relevancy? I would add that I think 'in' is mentioned in the stopwords file, so we can probably ignore the effect of that (?)
2. Or is this something in the (standard Drupal) schema that I need to change?

I appreciate that sometimes search is better for the visitor if it's inclusive; Google does return results even if it doesn't find perfect matches. But, stopwords and stemming aside, the client does require that searches return only results where all words appear in the content.

Comment: You need to make sure that the default operator is "AND" in schema.xml and re-index if you need to change it. (I think it is "OR" by default.)

Comment: I have '<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>' in schema.xml - is that the relevant setting? It's been in there for ages; but anyway we reindexed yesterday, so if this is the setting then it's definitely in there.

Comment: OK - I just noticed that you have a `qf` parameter. Since you're not using the dismax query parser, I don't think Solr will pay any mind to the `qf` parameter. Try adding `defType=dismax` to your query: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin You can even use extended dismax if you're using Solr 3.1 or later: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the dismax parser is defined in the <requestHandler> definition in solrconfig.xml ; adding it to the URL doesn't change the results, but see the comments below for what does seem to have helped (mm closer to 100%, op=AND and - rather unfortunately - turning off the SnowballPorter stemmer in schema.xml.)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the post at http://drupal.org/node/1783454, the Apache Solr Search Integration module makes use of the [mm](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29) param, which is more or less configured to effect rankings by how closely the keywords are in the dataset. Looking through the docs there are other ways you can use the parameter to effect rankings as well. Therefore the results produced by Apache Solr Search Integration are weighted more closely to the AND operator even though it will return more results as you add more keywords. The benefit of this param is that in cases where the user enters keywords that are too restrictive, results will still be returned. Displaying no results is a really quick way to guide people away from your site.

Comment: To return to the original question, then, of having stricter matching: mm needs to be set to be closer to 100%, or at least to a higher numeric value (it turns out that 100% and 1 are not synonymous; 1 in fact tends to the opposite of 100% as the search phrase gets longer) in order to make matching the original search phrase more strict. And this needs to be set in solrconfig.xml, apparently. And it's a <str name="mm">VALUE</str> child of <lst name="defaults"> in the <requestHandler name="drupal">. Am I doing all the right things there?

Comment: (If so it might be good if I can edit your answer to make it a bit clearer, and then I'd be happy accepting it: however, I've made edits of comments in the past and they seem to never get approved. Any thoughts?)

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the search ?
Maybe you could solr views to limit the search range ?
http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views
thanks

Nick

Comment: This isn't really a presentation issue at the Drupal side: Solr itself is returning just incorrect results. So I don't see how Apache Solr Views can make them correct.